# Bump map mask peeks through in rendered view

Tags: bump

I am trying to use some skin-like texture on the face of my model, and I use a mask multiplied with the bump map to get it only in the right places. At the white places I want the skin texture, at the black ones I do not. It almost works fine, but in rendered view I can see the mask peek through which is a problem at the eyes because there is a black mass on the eyes. Here's how it looks with the map attached:
[image]

And here's how the eyes look without the map attached:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I don't know if it will fix your problem but your Multiply node should probably be BEFORE the Bump node, then plug the Bump into the Normal input of the Principled BSDF

Comment: Yes, that worked, thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *Multiply* node should probably be BEFORE the *Bump* node, then plug the *Bump* into the *Normal* input of the *Principled BSDF*.